# Manejo de elementos Java Swing en otro Formulario

Tags: java, java-swing

¡Hola! Mi error es esto, fíjense que trato de manejar unos elementos de un formulario en el código de otro formulario, por ejemplo, el código que les presentaré está ubicado en el login, mientras que Home2 es el otro formulario

```
if (log.Logear(txtUsuario.getText(), txtContraseña.getText()) == 1) 
    {
        if (log.getId_tipo() == 1) 
        {
        Home2 h = new Home2();
        h.setVisible(true);
        h.btnActividades.setVisible(false);
        this.hide();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Y qué pasa cuando corres ese código?

Comment: Pues el btnActividades, no desaparece, entonces eso es lo que quiero que pase

Comment: agrega más código, el problema debe estar en como declaraste tu variable `btnActividades`, además de que como lo puisste no cimpila, trata siempre de poner un [mcve]

Comment: Es que `btnActividades` es un elemento swing que esta en otro formulario, que es Home2, que esta como objeto h.

Comment: Amigo debes cambiar el modificador de acceso del btnActividades  de private a public para que puedas modificar  las propiedades de dicho botón desde el formulario de Login. Eso  es lo que puedo analizar con la poca información que nos estás motrando.

Comment: @Cheox exactamento eso quiero, pero no se donde y como se hace eso:(

Comment: Hola amigo si estás usando el IDE de Netbeans puedes:
1-Hacer click sobre el btnActividades
2- Ir al panel de propiedades del objeto
3- Ir a la pestaña Code
4- Vas a la opción Modificador de variables (Variable Modifiers) click en el botón que aparece a la derecha uno contres puntos
5- En el JCombobox Acces selecciona public.
6- Das ok
Y podrás accesar al btnActividades desde el formulario de Login

Comment: @Cheox Muchas Gracias :D Ahora se algo nuevo gracias a ti, enserio te lo agradezco

Comment: Amigo ya he pasado los comentarios al área de respuesta. Si  mi respuesta te ayudó a resolver tu problema la puedes marcarla como usada para eso debes dar en el check situado a la parte izquierda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo debes cambiar el modificador de acceso del btnActividades de private a public para que puedas modificar las propiedades de dicho botón desde el formulario de Login.

Si estás usando el IDE de Netbeans puedes:

1. Hacer click sobre el btnActividades
2. Ir al panel de propiedades del objeto
3. Ir a la pestaña Code
4. Selecciona a la opción Variable Modifiers
5. Click en el botón que aparece a la derecha uno con tres puntos
6. En el JCombobox Acces selecciona public.
7. Das ok Y podrás acceder al btnActividades desde el formulario de Login

Espero haberte ayudado